# Spring SDN and dynamic query

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

We would like to order the results of a query by a property name. This property name can vary. According to this requirements which is the best solution to accomplish it with spring SDN?

The only solution that I found is to use the OGM `Session` and create the query dynamically.

Any suggestion? Maybe an enhancement on Spring SDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with Spring Data Neo4j or Spring Data in general (see: [Spring data JPA query with parameter properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802798/spring-data-jpa-query-with-parameter-properties) and [Query : property name in parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661014/query-property-name-in-parameter)).

Your best bet is to generate the query dynamically via `Session`.